# Which CSS attribute, if any, would control this?

Tags: html, css

I have the following list:

[alt text http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/2912/12922833.jpg](http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/2912/12922833.jpg)

How can I get the fourth item's text to wrap around but indent at the same level as the rest of the list? Is there some CSS attribute that controls this?

Comment: What does your CSS look like currently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try [`list-style-position`](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/css/classification/list-style-position.html):

```
li {
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

As [ricebowl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82548/ricebowl) remembered to comment, you might need to increase your left margin or padding to make the bullet points 'stay put', because instead of the bullet points being inside the `<li>`, they are now placed outside.

Comment: That just made all of my bullets disappear.

Comment: @ryeguy, you need to compensate for the `list-style-position`, by adding padding to the `li` try adding `padding-left: 2em`, or similar.

Comment: @ryeguy, well...if you wanted to upvote the comment I wouldn't complain... =p

Answer (score 0):

If it's a real list, that should be the default, but do as Henrik says anyway.

If it's not a real list, and you're just sticking an image of a bullet in there... then... Well that's slightly harder. Ideally you would use a proper list (`<ul><li>list item</li></ul>`)

If it's an image of a bullet, you could use padding and absolute positioning. If it's a HTML character for a bullet, you're stuffed.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your asking, I'm assuming you want it to look like you have it above. Because by default it shouldn't look like that.

the code example below will make it look like your image:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    ul li {
        padding-left: 5px;
        text-indent: 20px;
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </li>
    <li>text </li>
</ul>
```

and this code will make it look like what your asking:

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        width: 200px;
    }
</style>

<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </li>
    <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 ul li { padding-left: 25px; }
```